# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning when returning Primary Key in Node pg (Postgresql)

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I have this code to make a query to my postgres db

```
 getLeagueId = async (league_name) => {
    // Return the league id from a given league
    const client = this.connectToDatabase();
    await client.connect();
    try {
      const query = await client.query(`SELECT * FROM leagues
                                        WHERE name = '${league_name}';`);
      await client.end();
      return query.rows[0];
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(`An error occurred when fetching league ID: ${err}`);
    }
  };
```

And I get a return:

```
{"league_id":1,"name":"Premier League","type":"League","country":"England","logo":"https://media-3.api-sports.io/football/leagues/39.png","flag":"https://media-1.api-sports.io/flags/gb.svg"}
```

When I change the return to

```
return query.rows[0].name;
// I get the name Premier League
```

As soon as I change the return to

```
return query.rows[0].league_id;
```

I get the following error

```
express deprecated res.send(status): Use res.sendStatus(status) instead app.js:52:11
(node:274778) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: 1
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:248:11)
    at ServerResponse._implicitHeader (_http_server.js:239:8)
    at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:654:9)
    at ServerResponse.end (_http_outgoing.js:766:5)
    at ServerResponse.send (/home/stoffel/Documents/dailySports/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:232:10)
    at ServerResponse.json (/home/stoffel/Documents/dailySports/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:278:15)
    at ServerResponse.send (/home/stoffel/Documents/dailySports/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:162:21)
    at /home/stoffel/Documents/dailySports/app.js:55:11
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:274778) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:274778) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Everytime I try to access the primary key I get an error. I have tried with both postgres.js and pg and both give me this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express `res.send()` only sends an object, a String, or an Array-type response. You cannot send an integer-type response. Your `league_id` value type is an integer.

Visit this link for more information: https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.send